# How can i check collide of sprite and specific layer tile in Phaser?

Tags: html, phaser-framework

I make 2 tilemaps, on one land, on another staircase. I do the gravity and everything works fine with the ground, but I do not know how to check the contact with the tile ladder. I create so:

```js
//Ground
map.ground = game.add.tilemap('map-ground', 32, 32);
map.ground.addTilesetImage('tileset');
layer.ground = map.ground.createLayer(0);
layer.ground.setScale(3);
map.ground.setCollision(174);//ID grounds
//Ladders&Hide
map.laddersAndHide = game.add.tilemap('map-ladders&hide', 32, 32);
map.laddersAndHide.addTilesetImage('tileset');
layer.laddersAndHide = map.laddersAndHide.createLayer(0);
layer.laddersAndHide.setScale(3);
map.laddersAndHide.setCollision(168);// ID ladders
```

then he did such checks:

```js
game.physics.arcade.collide(player, layer.ground);
game.physics.arcade.collide(player, layer.laddersAndHide, function () {
    console.log(true);
});
```

Whereas I realized the collision with the ground blocked the collision with the stairs. When I removed the collision with the ground the ladder worked (though not as I needed, I could not pass through it). So I tried:

```js
game.physics.arcade.overlap(player, layer.laddersAndHide, testFunc, null, this);
```

Then the function testFunc was executed continuously. Perhaps due to the fact that I did not specify a particular id in the layer. But how can I say? Now I have stopped on this:

```js
game.physics.arcade.collide(player, [layer.ground, layer.laddersAndHide], function () {
     console.log(this);
});
```

I think maybe there's a way to put a check on what exactly layer was the contact?

I apologize for the English